# LoadRunner lr_eval_string loses last bytes of string

Tags: loadrunner

LoadRunner code:

```
web_set_max_html_param_len("15000");
web_reg_save_param("param1", "LB=AAA", "RB=BBB", LAST);
//  saved around 10 kB of String
//...
fputs(lr_eval_string("{param1}");
// printed only the 1st 8 kB of param1
```

Can I somehow get all of the `param1`?

Answer (score 1):

`web_reg_save_param_X` functions saves the whole text following the defined conditions (boundaries, regular expression etc.).
The size of saved string can be validated using web_save_param_length function like in example below:

```
web_set_max_html_param_len("102400");
web_reg_save_param("param1", "LB=Table of Contents", "RB=1 Introduction", "Search=Body", LAST);
web_url("test","URL=https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt", LAST);
web_save_param_length("param1", "Base=Decimal", LAST );
lr_message("saved parameter size is: [%s]", lr_eval_string("{param1_Length}"));
```

Output:

```
Notify: Saving Parameter "param1_Length = 19237".
saved parameter size is: [19237]
```

Generally, parameter is not a string and can include null character and in this case printing will show only the part before it…